# Why changing visibility/display on focus does not work?

Tags: html, css

I've gotten an idea to make a search "button" upon clicking which the input box would show up and stretch. However instead of using an invisible checkbox I decided to try and use the label since clicking the label would put focus on the element the label is connected to. And while giving focus and doing basic transformations do work, I can't seem to hide/show the textbox either using `visibility: hidden/visible` or `display: none/inline-block`. And I don't want to just rely on opacity since the textbox can be found/clicked even while it's hidden.

Current attempt: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8cF/2/)

Why doesn't this work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Elements that are not visible cannot receive focus, therefore the `:focus` psuedo-class cannot apply.

Using `width` and `opacity` seems to produce a reasonable effect.

Comment: I see... so it's either opacity or using the checkbox trick. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use opacity only, `visibility:hidden` or `display:none;` are not suppose to allow focus (IMHO), since element are not visible.

```
form label {
    font-size: 23px;
}

#box {
    width: 0px;
  opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: 200ms;
    -moz-transition: 200ms;
    -ms-transition: 200ms;
    -o-transition: 200ms;
    transition: 200ms;        
}

#box:focus {
   opacity:1;
    width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6h8cF/7/

Comment: "are not suppose to allow focus" and if I want to manipulate an *invisible* input element to use the copy event?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get a focus from a label since it is not a focussable element. 
See BoltClocks answer here : [Anyway to have a label respond to :focus CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978239/anyway-to-have-a-label-respond-to-focus-css)

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6NNs/

Change from :focus to :hover.

Resulting CSS should be:

```
form label {
    font-size: 23px;
}

#box {
    width: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: 200ms;
    -moz-transition: 200ms;
    -ms-transition: 200ms;
    -o-transition: 200ms;
    transition: 200ms;        
}

#box:hover{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;    
    width: 50px;
}
```