# Show a block using focus()

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is :

- to show a popin when the user clicks on a button
- to hide the popin when the user clicks elsewhere

I've tried this solution, and it works great : [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

But I wanted to try something differently, I wanted to try `focus()`

So I made this code :

```css
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div:focus
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script>
function show()
{
 document.getElementById("element").focus();
}

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="click me!"/>
<div id="element"tabindex="-1">

</div>
After you clicked the button, click elsewhere to remove the red background
```

And it works great, now I want to hide the block and show it when the user clicks the button, I just added `display: block` and `display: none`, that's the only difference between the two versions

```css
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: none;
}

div:focus
{
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script>
function show()
{
 document.getElementById("element").focus();
}

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="click me!"/>
<div id="element"tabindex="-1">

</div>
```

And it's not working anymore, can someone tell me why?

Comment: If the div is the next sibling to the input, you could give the div a class such as `default-hidden` and write styles: `div.default-hidden { display: none }` and `input:focus + div.default-hidden { display: block }`. No need for the show function.

Comment: Thank you @KyleRichardson, I didn't know that the `+` operator existed

Comment: It is a very useful selector. I wish there was a previous sibling selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot focus an object that has `display: none` applied.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351546/5651536):

> Elements that are not visible cannot receive focus, therefore the :focus psuedo-class cannot apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with CSS using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). When the button is focused, the sibling div appears:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: none;
}

button:focus + div {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="">click me!</button>
<div id="element" tabindex="-1"></div>
```