# How can I include all the components into Tab order?

Tags: html

How can I include all the components in the html page - so each time I press TAB, I get the next element in the page, **including labels!!**
for example:

```html
    <div class="input">
        <h1 tabindex="0">I need that all the components will be in the list of tab-order, Including labels!</h1>
        <label class="narrow-control label-top-right" for="txtName">name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtName" class="inputText"/>
        <label class="narrow-control label-top-right" for="txtAge">age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtAge" class="inputText"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does "get the next element in the page" mean? Get how? Why?

Comment: @PeeHaa when the user press on tab - the first element will be focus, in the example - h1, after i want to be focus on the label... how can I do it?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/5978239/508666. A label cannot be focused. What would it do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyway to have a label respond to :focus CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978239/anyway-to-have-a-label-respond-to-focus-css)