# Style input component in panelGrid when outputLabel is focused

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

Am using JSF and Primefaces .. And i need when i focus on the outlabel the input text gets background color
This is my code :

---

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" style="border:0px none;background:none" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank ">
   <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.PurchaseReturns_Txt_Document_NO}"   />
   <p:inputText readonly="true" value="#{quotationMB.instance.object.quotationid}"/>
</p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid styleClass="datePick ui-panelgrid-blank " columns="2" layout="grid"  style="border:0px none;background:none">
   <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.RequestForQuotation_Txt_Date}" />
   <p:calendar  value="#{quotationMB.instance.object.validto}" locale="de" navigator="true" pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" showOn="button" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

---

*************************JAVA Script*******************************

I have tried this code .. It worked but on the whole input texts that i have in my page :

---

```
 $('.ui-outputlabel').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.ui-inputtext').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

---

Comment: And please try to create good titles...

Comment: I retracted my duplicate vote, since it cannot be used in combination with `p:panelGrid`. You need to go up to the `tr` and search from there.

Comment: When you are copying and pasting code from the internet try to understand what it does and not blindly use it and hope that it'll simply just work.

Comment: Guys i just need a code that can make the input gets background color when i click anywhere on the outlabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in your question.

To start off, you cannot focus a `p:outputLabel` (which is rendered as an HTML `label`). Clicking the label will focus the linked field. Which brings us to the second issue.

In order for an `p:outputLabel` to work as specified in the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/outputLabel.xhtml) (validation errors, error styling, required indicator, etc.), you need to use the `for` attribute to link it to the input component (as in regular HTML).

So, if you add `for` to your labels, you can simply style the input fields using the `:focus` CSS selector.

Technically you could get your click listener working like this (but that would not make sense):

```
$("label").click(function(){
    document.getElementById(this.htmlFor).style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

It would make more sense to add a `focus` and `blur` listener to input fields and use the listeners to toggle a CSS class on the corresponding label. For example:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $("label[for=\""+ this.id +"\"]").addClass("focus");
});
$("input").blur(function(){
    $("label[for=\""+ this.id +"\"]").removeClass("focus");
});
```

See also:

- [Anyway to have a label respond to :focus CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978239/anyway-to-have-a-label-respond-to-focus-css)

Comment: This idea came through to my head at the beginning .. But i have to add "for" for the whole input fields that i have one by one .. So is there any other solution ?

Comment: You could create a custom tag which combines the two. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component

Comment: .. but without `for` your labels are pretty much useless. I would advice to add them, even if it requires a bit of work.